# Scrapy not pulling closing prices from Yahoo! Finance

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to pull closing prices and percentage changes for three tickers from Yahoo! Finance using Scrapy. However, I get no data even though I've confirmed my XPaths work and get me to the right place on the actual page, using the console in Chrome. Could someone let me know what might be happening here?

items.py:

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field

class InvestmentItem(Item):
    ticker = Field()
    closing_px = Field()
    closing_pct = Field()
```

investment_spider.py

```
from scrapy import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from investment.items import InvestmentItem

class InvestmentSpider(Spider):
    name = "investment"
    allowed_domains = ["finance.yahoo.com"]
    start_urls = ["https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/SPY?p=SPY", "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/DIA?p=DIA", "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/QQQ?p=QQQ"]

    def parse(self, response):
        results = Selector(response).xpath('//div[@class="D(ib) Mend(20px)"]')

        for result in results:
            item = InvestmentItem()
            item['closing_px'] = result.xpath('//span[@class="Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)"]/text()').extract()[0]
            item['closing_pct'] = result.xpath('//span[@class="Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(500) Pstart(10px) Fz(24px) C($dataRed)"]/text()').extract()[0]
            yield item
```

output from console:

```
2020-03-22 23:42:26 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 2.0.0 started (bot: investment)
2020-03-22 23:42:26 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.5.0.0, libxml2 2.9.10, cssselect 1.1.0, parsel 1.5.2, w3lib 1.21.0, Twisted 19.10.0, Python 3.8.2 (v3.8.2:7b3ab5921f, Feb 24 2020, 17:52:18) - [Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)], pyOpenSSL 19.1.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019), cryptography 2.8, Platform macOS-10.15.3-x86_64-i386-64bit
2020-03-22 23:42:26 [scrapy.utils.log] DEBUG: Using reactor: twisted.internet.selectreactor.SelectReactor
2020-03-22 23:42:26 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings:
{'BOT_NAME': 'investment',
 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'investment.spiders',
 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True,
 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['investment.spiders']}
2020-03-22 23:42:26 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: 4d82e058cd5967c1
2020-03-22 23:42:26 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.memusage.MemoryUsage',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2020-03-22 23:42:26 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2020-03-22 23:42:26 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2020-03-22 23:42:26 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2020-03-22 23:42:26 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2020-03-22 23:42:26 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2020-03-22 23:42:26 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2020-03-22 23:42:26 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://finance.yahoo.com/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2020-03-22 23:42:27 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/SPY?p=SPY> (referer: None)
2020-03-22 23:42:27 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/QQQ?p=QQQ> (referer: None)
2020-03-22 23:42:28 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/DIA?p=DIA> (referer: None)
2020-03-22 23:42:29 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2020-03-22 23:42:29 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 923,
 'downloader/request_count': 4,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 4,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 495443,
 'downloader/response_count': 4,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 4,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 2.296482,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 23, 3, 42, 29, 66553),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 4,
 'log_count/INFO': 10,
 'memusage/max': 48963584,
 'memusage/startup': 48963584,
 'response_received_count': 4,
 'robotstxt/request_count': 1,
 'robotstxt/response_count': 1,
 'robotstxt/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 3,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 3,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 3,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 3,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 23, 3, 42, 26, 770071)}
2020-03-22 23:42:29 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Required pages are dynamically rendered by React.
The required information is inside the **script** tag and the variable **root.App.main**

To receive info i use this [docs](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/dynamic-content.html#topics-parsing-javascript).
Another option is to use [Splash](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash) or [Selenium](https://github.com/clemfromspace/scrapy-selenium) rendering.

Working example:

```
from scrapy import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from investment.items import InvestmentItem

import json

class InvestmentSpider(Spider):
    name = "investment"
    allowed_domains = ["finance.yahoo.com"]
    start_urls = ["https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/SPY?p=SPY", "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/DIA?p=DIA", "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/QQQ?p=QQQ"]

    def parse(self, response):
        pattern = r'\broot\.App\.main\s*=\s*(\{.*?\})\s*;\s*\n'
        json_data = response.css('script::text').re_first(pattern)
        price = json.loads(json_data)['context']['dispatcher']['stores']['QuoteSummaryStore']['price']

        item = InvestmentItem()
        item['closing_px'] = price['regularMarketPrice']['fmt']
        item['closing_pct'] = price['regularMarketChange']['fmt']

        yield item
```

Comment: A follow-up question: how do you know that the pages are rendered in React / that the info is inside a script tag (I don't see any)? Sorry for newbie questions, pretty new to web dev / scraping

Comment: I got information about this from the page source code. React can be identified by several distinctive features: 1. By the attribute 'data-reactroot' of a div tag in the html source. 2. The word "react" in the names of script tag files. 3. Data can be determined by the line "root.App.main".

Answer (score 0):

hope this will help you

```
class InvestmentSpider(Spider):
    name = "investment"


    def start_requests(self):
        urls = ["https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/SPY?p=SPY", "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/DIA?p=DIA", "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/QQQ?p=QQQ"]
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)


    def parse(self, response):
        data = response.xpath('//div[@class="D(ib) Mend(20px)"]/span/text()').extract()

        item = InvestmentItem()
        item['closing_px'] = data[0] #1st span
        item['closing_pct'] = data[1] #2nd span

        yield item
```